# UPDATE SET WHERE Partially working on listbox - Microsoft Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba, sql-update

I'm totally stumped at this one.. Skip to bottom to read problem

Here's my listbox (**DocumentList**) that takes the fields from the '**Documents**' Table:

```
Document Name   Status         Notes                  Consultation Notes
Doc A           Started        Document Started       Aim to process on 05/05/16
Doc B           Processing     Document Processing    Aim to complete on 05/05/16
Doc C           Complete       Complete on 01/01/16   N/A
```

I have the onclick event set so that when you select a row from the listbox, it assigns each field to a text box/Combobox.

textboxes/Combobox names:

```
txtDocument
StatusCombo
txtNotes
txtConNotes
```

code for each one in 'DocumentList' click event:

```
Private Sub DocumentList_Click()

txtDocument = DocumentList.Column(0)
StatusCombo = DocumentList.Column(1)
txtNotes = DocumentList.Column(2)
txtConNotes = DocumentList.Column(3)
```

After the data is assigned to them from the listbox, you can edit it. I have an update button, which when pressed will replace everything in the database with everything in the textboxes/Combobox. The listbox is then re-queried and displays the updated data.

Heres the code for my update button:

```
Private Sub UpdateButton_Click()

CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [Documents] " & _
"SET [Document Name] = '" & Me.txtDocument & "'" & _
", [Status] = '" & StatusCombo.Value & "'" & _
", [Notes] = '" & Me.txtNotes & "'" & _
", [Consultation Notes] = '" & Me.txtConNotes & "'" & _
"WHERE [Document Name] =  '" & DocumentList.Column(0) & "'" & _
"AND [Status] =  '" & DocumentList.Column(1) & "'" & _
"AND [Notes] =  '" & DocumentList.Column(2) & "'" & _
"AND [Consultation Notes] =  '" & DocumentList.Column(3) & "'"


DocumentList.Requery
End Sub
```

My problem is the code only works on 2 out of 3 of the documents. All aspects of the code work, but only on some of the documents. This doesn't make any sense to me. At first I thought it may be a spelling error, but even if it was, none of the documents should get updated.. But some of them do, 1 doesn't..

Any ideas why this code updates some documents, but doesn't update others?

Comment: Store your `UPDATE` statement text in a string variable, *strUpdate*.  Then add `Debug.Print strUpdate` and execute it like this: `CurrentDb.Execute strUpdate, dbFailOnError`  Does Access then give you more information about the failed updates?

Comment: I've found the error.. Some documents don't have anything stored in the last field 'Consultation Notes'. Those documents are the ones I'm unable to update. However, if I put a value into that table field directly, then try to update them from the form it works..   What I don't understand is; I can then set that value back to nothing, but can continue to update it as normal

Comment: When `[Consultation Notes]` is Null, it is not equal to `"'" & DocumentList.Column(3) & "'"`  I think your task would be simpler if you add an autonumber primary key, *ID*, to the `[Documents]` table.  Then include *ID* in the list box (doesn't have to be visible), and use that value in the `WHERE` clause to target the row you want to update.  That should be simpler than the `WHERE` clause you have now, and avoid the complication of "Null is never equal to anything, not even another Null".  Also consider a parameter query for the `UPDATE`

Comment: @HansUp Thank you very much for informing me; I thought an empty field would be the same value as an empty string, e.g. ""; I guess that's where the problem lied. Your alternative solution helped a lot, simplified my code too as I didn't need all of those WHERE clause, only one.  If you'd like to put it as an answer so I can accept it feel free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is updated when `[Documents].[Consultation Notes]` is Null, because the `WHERE` clause targets an empty string instead ... `"'" & DocumentList.Column(3) & "'"` ... so no matching row is found.

The task would be simpler if you add an autonumber primary key, *ID*, to the `[Documents]` table. Then include *ID* in the list box *Row Source*, and use that value in the `WHERE` clause to target the row you want to update. (The *ID* column doesn't have to be visible in the list box; you can set its column width property to zero.)

Then your `WHERE` clause can be much simpler: just target the record whose *ID* matches the *ID* column value of the selected list box row.  That strategy would also avoid the complication of *"Null is never equal to anything, not even another Null"*.

Finally, consider a parameter query for the `UPDATE` instead of concatenating values into a string variable.